# Android MidiManager, Bluetooth and Peripheral BLE

Tags: android, midi, android-bluetooth

I'm writing now something that's using [Android Midi API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/package-summary.html).

The examples shows ability to use bluetooth midi devices but only as Central BLE device.

```
m.openBluetoothDevice(bluetoothDevice, callback, handler);
```

However I don't see any way I can do Peripheral BLE (meaning my device will be discoverable and handle incoming connection requests).

I've started using `BluetoothLeAdvertiser` or `BluetoothGattServer` but still I don't understand how I hook them up with the Midi API provided with Android (API 23+...)

Answer (score 0):

Well I am writing something related and what I found helpfull is source code and working samples of library from kshoji BLE-MIDI-for-Android or any of its newer forks. Still looks like I am able to use it just as Peripheral and Central I need to write myself, so looks like I am going to mix it up by multiple approaches as implementation of central is kind of messy for me because it look like it is connecting automatically to all found devices what I cannot understand reason at all. But that part you where looking for, looks like is working quite well, just by using this lib I was able to get working peripheral bluetooth midi and send midi note on messages to my iPAD to apps like Korg Gadget or AUM from virtual keyboard on android.
https://github.com/kshoji/BLE-MIDI-for-Android